# Definition of Galois Cohomology

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

For Galois cohomology, one uses the cohomology constructed for profinite groups instead of the usual group cohomology. In other words, one also uses/takes into account the Krull topology we have on the Galois groups.

Is there a significant reason why we are using this definition of Galois cohomology?

For infinite Galois theory, I know that the topology is needed to construct a generalization of the fundamental theorem for finite Galois theory. But is there also a similar reason why we want to consider the topology when talking about cohomology for Galois groups?

Let $G$ be a group, and $M$ be a $G$-module. Then in terms of group cohomology, we have $H^{0}(G,M):=M^{G}$, and $H^{1}(G,M)=\{\text{1-cocycles}\}/\{\text{1-coboundaries}\}$.

When considering profinite groups $G$, we consider discrete $G$-modules $M$. These are $G$-modules such that the group action is continuous with respect to the discrete topology. Then the cohomology groups are given by $H_{c}^{0}(G,M):=M^{G}$, and $H_{c}^{1}(G,M)=\{\text{cont. 1-cocycles}\}/\{\text{cont. 1-coboundaries}\}$. In general, $H_{c}^{1}(G,M)$ does not have to be equal to $H^{1}(G,M)$.

Now a profinite group (for instance a Galois group), is obiously also just a
group. Meaning that we could also just consider the usual group cohomology, i.e. $H^{1}(G,M)$ instead of $H^{1}_{c}(G,M)$. Or in other words, just skip the continuity condition.

So I wonder, why do we want also want to take into account the continuity condition. Wouldn't it be a lot easier if we just use the basic group cohomology? Or are there any significant results for which we need the extra continuity condition.

Comment: Can you expand? All I know is that usually $A$ has the discrete topology and $G_K$ acts continuously, the stabilizer of an element and the $f^{-1}(f(1))$ of a cocycle will be an open subgroup ($G_L$ for a finite extension).

Comment: @reuns I clarified a bit more. I understand that the question might be a bit vague, but I just wonder why people are skipping to cohomology theory for profinite groups, instead of just using the basic group cohomology. For finite groups, these two definitions obviously coincide.

Comment: Obviously because things factor through a finite extension, but it is unclear to me what is the good definition for $H^r,r\ge 2$ ie. if $G_K$ acts continuously on $A$ with discrete topology is enough.